# How to get input file to open?

Tags: c++, input, file-io

For this project, we are supposed to use an input and output file to better organize our data.  Howvever, for whatever reason, every time I rube the program it says

```
"File couldn't open. Terminating.

Process finished with exit code 1"
```

I have tried several different methods to try and get the program to open the file (using different commands, changing filename, etc), however each time it gives me the above statement.

Here is the code for my program (please note there is much more code than this.  However, this is the only area that uses the input file, so I am confident that the error is residing somewhere withing here):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

#ifdef _MSC_VER // Memory leak check
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#define VS_MEM_CHECK _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#else
#define VS_MEM_CHECK
#endif

using namespace std;

const int NUM_GRADES = 5;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    VS_MEM_CHECK               // Enable memory leak check
    ifstream inputFile; // Reading Input file
    inputFile.open(argv[1]);
    if (inputFile.is_open()) { // Checks if file opened succesfully
        cout << "Input File opened successfully.\n";
    } else {
        cout << "File couldn't open. Terminating.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int numStudents;
    int numExams;
    inputFile >> numStudents >> numExams;
    inputFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');

    string *arrayNames = new string[numStudents]; // Intializes Students Array
    double *arrayTotalGrade = new double[numStudents]; // Initializes Total Score Array
    double *arrayAverages = new double[numExams]; // Initializes Average Score Array
    int **arrayScores = new int *[numStudents]; // Initializes Scores Array
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; ++i) {
        arrayScores[i] = new int[numExams];
    }
    int **arrayGradeCount = new int *[numExams]; // Initializes Grade Count Array
    for (int i = 0; i < numExams; ++i) {
        arrayGradeCount[i] = new int[NUM_GRADES];
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_GRADES; ++j) {
            arrayGradeCount[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; ++i) {
        string line;
        string name;
        getline(inputFile, line);
        size_t p = 0;
        while (!isdigit(line[p])) ++p;    // line[p] is the location of the first digit on the line

        name = line.substr(0, p - 1); // Gets name from file, p-1 removes an extra whitespace.
        arrayNames[i] = name;
        line = line.substr(p); // Isolates scores on line
        istringstream iss(line); // Puts line (now with only scores' values) into an istringstream
        for (int j = 0; j < numExams; ++j) // Puts scores from istringstream into arrayScores onto row 'i'
        {
            int scores;
            iss >> scores;
            arrayScores[i][j] = scores;
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Guessing here: MSVS does not put your executable where you think it does. You should be using the Windows Terminal to execute your program, _not_ the VS IDE.

Comment: Im in Clion, so i think that the layout is a bit different.

Comment: I started it from the command prompt and it says that the input file is opened successfully.

Comment: So, if im understanding it correctly, its not working becuase Clion simpy cant open the file.  There is overall nothing wrong with the code?